# How to do JAX_RS one connection for all the affected method each call?

Tags: java, web-services, connection, jax-rs

I'm new on creating Java rest web service and I'm confused if I'm doing the right way. What I want is to make one connection for each call to all of my method. Is it best practice to send connection via parameter?

```
@GET
@Path("BasicInfo/{id}")
// Method to get basic information  
private BasicInfo getBasicInfo(@PathParam("id") String pid)
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    List<BasicInfo> info = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        String qry = "SELECT firstname, municipal_id FROM user_tbl WHERE id = ?";

        String username = "test";
        String password = "test";
        con = DB.getConnection(username, password);
        ps = con.prepareStatement(qry);
        ps.setString(1, pid);          

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
            String municipal_id = rs.getString("municipal_id");  
            String municipal_name = Fx.getMunicipalInfo(con, municipal_id);

            BasicInfo bInfo = new BasicInfo();
            bInfo.setFirstname( firstname );
            bInfo.setMunicipality_name( municipal_name );

            info.add(bInfo);
        }

    } catch(SQLException  | NullPointerException e) {
        //logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error : ", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ps != null) { ps.close(); }
            if (con != null) { con.close(); }
        } catch(SQLException sqlex) {}
    }

    return details;
}

// functions 
public class Fx {
   public String getMunicipalInfo(Connection con, String pmunicipalId) 
   {
       //Connection con = null;
       PreparedStatement ps = null;
       String municipalityName = "";

       try {
           String qry = "SELECT municipal_name FROM municipality WHERE id = ?";

           //con = DB.getConnection();
           ps = con.prepareStatement(qry);
           ps.setString(1, pmunicipalId);          

           ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

           if (rs.next()) {
               municipalityName = rs.getString("municipal_name ");
           }

       } catch(SQLException  | NullPointerException e) {
           //logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error : ", e.getMessage());
       } finally {
           try {
               if (ps != null) { ps.close(); }
               //if (con != null) { con.close(); }
           } catch(SQLException sqlex) {}
        }

        return municipalityName ;
   }
}

// getter and setter
public class BasicInfo {
    private String firstname;
    private String municipality_name;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getMunicipality_name() {
        return municipality_name;
    }

    public void setMunicipality_name(String municipality_name) {
        this.municipality_name = municipality_name;
    }
}

// Class for database connection
public class DB {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DB");
    public static Connection getConnection(String username, String password) 
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {            
            Context initcontext = new InitialContext();
            Context envcontext  = (Context) initcontext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) envcontext.lookup("jndi/ds");
            connection = ds.getConnection(username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error {0}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend using one connection for every API call. You should look up ``connection pool``, where connections can be retrieved from and reused when requests to the database are required.

Comment: Thanks for the info. i will research on how to do it using connection pool

Comment: May i know if connection pooling is application when i use "Use Database Credentials" cause when i connect to the database i send username and password ex.: datasource.getConnection("username", "password");